# Haskell : multiple declarations of "<function name>" ...?

Tags: haskell

Hey guys so here is my code on which I get the weird error of "Multiple Declarations of mirror". I have other functions before that but none of them are named mirror... Any ideas?

```
mirror :: BinTree a -> BinTree a
mirror = undefined
mirror (Node tL x tR) = Node x mirror tR mirror tL
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Multiple definitions of a function must have the same number of arguments left of the equals sign.  This is not required from a theory standpoint (note: one of the definitons could certainly be a lambda or return another function) but people seem to like it as such definitions typically indicate a bug.

Specifically, you have one definition with zero arguments:

```
mirror = undefined
```

And one definition with one argument:

```
mirror (Node tL x tR) = Node x mirror tR mirror tL
```

you probably want:

```
mirror _              = undefined
mirror (Node tL x tR) = Node x mirror tR mirror tL
```

Comment: He would really want to swap the order, because the order of resolution for pattern matching is top to bottom, isn't it?

Comment: @behklilr I think people are reading too much into the actual code.  `undefined` is often used as a placeholder as it allows type-checking of the rest of the code before putting in another case - in this case a case for some sort of `Bin` or `Nil` constructor.

Comment: I actually removed the undefined. It was completely my fault for not reading my assignment. The undefined was placed there to be replaced with the actual content...Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the issue with this specific example, but since this is the first result on Google for "multiple definitions Haskell", I figured I should contribute what the problem was for me:

If you are defining the function multiple times using pattern-matching with some of the arguments, all of the definitions must be consecutive. If there is other code in between them, they are considered separate definitions.

Example: the following is invalid because the definition of `b` divides the definitions of `a`:

```hs
frobnicate :: Bool -> String
frobnicate True = "foo"
b = "bar"
frobnicate False = b
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 2 and line 3 have conflicting types: you've defined `mirror` to be the constant `undefined`, and then attempt to define it as a one-argument function. Removing line 2 should fix the problem; it's not clear why you wrote it in the first place.

Comment: Actually the type is not the problem. `undefined` has type `a`, which matches any other type.

Comment: I think it's more accurate to say that undefined is a member of every type. This includes the type `a -> b`, i.e., one-argument functions.

Answer (score 0):

You have conflicting definitions for `mirror`. The first clause,

```
mirror = undefined
```

is a catch-all, so the definition is considered finished by the compiler. The next clause is then considered to start a new definition. You should remove the `undefined` line.

Comment: @GeorgiAngelov: the `undefined` is probably intended to signal "fill in" while making sure the program compiles. You'll have to remove it to get a working program.