# Expand a function in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, recursion

In my homework, we are given a regular expression. I have to return an e-NFA. I'm trying to build the `delta` function. So far I have:

```
module ConsENFA where

import Data.Set (Set, fromList, singleton, empty)
import RegEx
import ENFA

epsilon :: RegExp Char
epsilon = Symbol 'e'

deltaTest :: RegExp Char -> Int -> (Int -> Char -> Set Int)
deltaTest (Symbol sym) start = delta
    where
        delta :: Int -> Char -> Set Int
        delta start sym = singleton (start + 1)

deltaTest (Star re) start = delta
    where
        delta :: Int -> Char -> Set Int
        delta = deltaTest re (start + 1)
        delta start epsilon = fromList[1, 3]
```

I got the error

```
ConsENFA.hs:19:9: error:
Conflicting definitions for `delta'
Bound at: ConsENFA.hs:19:9-13
          ConsENFA.hs:20:9-13
```

which I assume means that I can't expand the pattern matching like that, I can't add more states.

I first define `delta` for a single label and then I add more definitions to the previously defined `delta`, but it's not working. What's the correct way to do it?

Comment: The actual error is due to `delta` being defined as a function with arity 0 and arity 2 in the 2nd equation for `deltaTest`. It's not clear what the actual definition should be. Another (unreported) error is the attempt to use the value of `epsilon` as part of the pattern match.

Comment: @chepner The use of `epsilon` shouldn't throw an error; it's just name shadowing. That might be unintended, but it's  not a compile error.

Comment: A quick [search of StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhaskell%5D+conflicting+definition) turned up someone else who had the [same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18563575/haskell-multiple-declarations-of-function-name/18563628).

Comment: @crockeea I'll pretend that's what I meant by unreported :)

Comment: @crockeea Apologies, I tried many keywords in my search but couldn't find an answer since I did not know the correct terminology.

Comment: @lombardo2 All I did was search for the keywords in the error that GHC reported; no extra knowledge required!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All definitions of a function must have the same *arity*, i.e., the same number of function arguments. You define `delta` in three lines:

1. The first line is a type signature.
2. The second line is a *definition* of `delta` with arity zero (no arguments to the left of the `=`)
3. The third line is another *definition* of `delta` with arity two (two arguments to the left of the `=`)

The two definitions have a different arity, so the compiler tells you there are conflicting definitions.

Ask yourself: What is the inteded behavior of `delta`? The compiler will look at the definitions of `delta` in the order they are defined, and choose the first one where a pattern match succeeds. Since there are no arguments in the first definition (and hence no patterns to match), it will always succeed and the second definition will never be called.

Comment: Thanks, this made it click. Made it work doing `delta x y = deltaTest re (start + 1) x y` after the particular case

Comment: @lombardo2 Fine, that fixes the arity issue, but the first definition is now completely generic, and the second definition will still never be called! (You should be getting a warning about `Pattern match is redundant` when you compile.) This will not do what you intend it to.

Comment: Yeah, just noticed. I tough `start` was the same `start` before where, a constant, but guess it's not. It's hard to grasp functional programming after thinking so much in imperative

Comment: It hasn't to do with imperative in this case. You just need to get used to the scoping rules. An identifier occuring in a pattern is always a "new" one and will shadow any others with the same name in its scope. Now, the next thing to learn is to get a feeling where patterns occur. :)

Comment: @Ingo Is there a way to use the outer one? A quick search in learnyouahaskell did not provided me one.

Comment: You could use guards, i.e. `delta x y | x == start, y == epsilon = .....`

Comment: @Ingo Thanks, that's what I did.